# with tf.device(DEVICE): model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode = "inference", model_dir = LOGS_DIR, config = config)

Tags: keras, tensorflow, faster-rcnn, keras-rl

ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
509 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 510 preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
511 except TypeError as err:

/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
1106 if ret is None:
-> 1107 ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
1108

/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in _autopacking_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
959 return NotImplemented
--> 960 return _autopacking_helper(v, inferred_dtype, name or "packed")
961

/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in _autopacking_helper(list_or_tuple, dtype, name)
921 elems_as_tensors.append(
--> 922 constant_op.constant(elem, dtype=dtype, name=str(i)))
923 return gen_array_ops.pack(elems_as_tensors, name=scope)

/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
195 tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
--> 196 value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
197 dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)

/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
423 if values is None:
--> 424 raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
425 # if dtype is provided, forces numpy array to be the type

ValueError: None values not supported.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Please put your code.

Comment: with tf.device(DEVICE):
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=LOGS_DIR,config=config)

Comment: code is available at : https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/samples/nucleus/inspect_nucleus_model.ipynb

Comment: program which raises the raises the error is (in keras) :with tf.device(DEVICE): model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=LOGS_DIR,config=config)

Comment: with tf.device(DEVICE): model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=LOGS_DIR,config=config)